# How be a query with mongoose and express for attribute reference?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to query Notes using the id of the author reference, I tried but it doesn't work as I expect.

noteModel
[image]

noteController
[image]

noteRoute[image]

I want to learn more examples of "difficult queries" if you can do other example with more filters I will be happy!

Comment: What is the content of `req.params.author`?, and what is the result?

Comment: is the reference to _id "user", when I call that peticion always response the first note

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved it!!

```
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId( req.params.id);
    const notexautor = await Note.find({author: id}).populate('author');
    res.json(notexautor);
```